# Flutter Getx state with with StateMixin can't trigger onLoading state

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Why loading indicator not show on the screen before the data is displayed? Even though I have provided a loading indicator in my code?

Here I have used `StateMixin` on the controller and have created a listener with name `proposal`

```
class BaseController extends GetxController with StateMixin<List<Proposal>> {
  late PageController pageController;
  final dio = Dio();

  final ProposalApi _proposalApi = ProposalApi();

  RxList<Proposal> listProposal = <Proposal>[].obs;

  List<Widget> pages = [
    const HomeTab(),
    ProposalTab(),
    ReportTab(),
    const ProfileTab(),
  ];

  @override
  void onInit() {
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    super.onInit();
    fetchProposal();

    debounce(
      txtSearch,
      (_) => fetchProposalBySearch(txtSearch.value),
      time: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
  }

  void fetchProposal() async {
    try {
      final response = await _proposalApi.getProposal();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final proposalModel = ProposalByTypeModel.fromJson(response.data);
        if (proposalModel.data != null) {
          listProposal.assignAll(proposalModel.data!);
          change(listProposal, status: RxStatus.success());
        }
        if (proposalModel.data!.isEmpty) {
          change(null, status: RxStatus.empty());
        }
      } else {
        change(
          null,
          status: RxStatus.error(
            'Failed to get data',
          ),
        );
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      final ApiException apiException = ApiException.fromDioError(e);
      change(null, status: RxStatus.error(apiException.toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

My Model

```
import 'dart:convert';

ProposalModel proposalModelFromJson(String str) =>
    ProposalModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String proposalModelToJson(ProposalModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ProposalModel {
  int? currentPage;
  List<Proposal>? data;
  String? firstPageUrl;
  int? from;
  int? lastPage;
  String? lastPageUrl;
  List<Link>? links;
  String? nextPageUrl;
  String? path;
  int? perPage;
  dynamic prevPageUrl;
  int? to;
  int? total;

  ProposalModel({
    this.currentPage,
    this.data,
    this.firstPageUrl,
    this.from,
    this.lastPage,
    this.lastPageUrl,
    this.links,
    this.nextPageUrl,
    this.path,
    this.perPage,
    this.prevPageUrl,
    this.to,
    this.total,
  });

  factory ProposalModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProposalModel(
        currentPage: json["current_page"],
        data: json["data"] == null
            ? []
            : List<Proposal>.from(
                json["data"]!.map((x) => Proposal.fromJson(x))),
        firstPageUrl: json["first_page_url"],
        from: json["from"],
        lastPage: json["last_page"],
        lastPageUrl: json["last_page_url"],
        links: json["links"] == null
            ? []
            : List<Link>.from(json["links"]!.map((x) => Link.fromJson(x))),
        nextPageUrl: json["next_page_url"],
        path: json["path"],
        perPage: json["per_page"],
        prevPageUrl: json["prev_page_url"],
        to: json["to"],
        total: json["total"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "current_page": currentPage,
        "data": data == null
            ? []
            : List<dynamic>.from(data!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "first_page_url": firstPageUrl,
        "from": from,
        "last_page": lastPage,
        "last_page_url": lastPageUrl,
        "links": links == null
            ? []
            : List<dynamic>.from(links!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "next_page_url": nextPageUrl,
        "path": path,
        "per_page": perPage,
        "prev_page_url": prevPageUrl,
        "to": to,
        "total": total,
      };
}

class Proposal {
  int? id;
  String? uuidItem;
  int? proposalId;
  String? ro;
  String? ao;
  String? kota;
  String? venue;
  String? title;
  String? deskripsi;
  String? jenisEvent;
  String? targetAudience;
  String? klasifikasiEvent;
  DateTime? startDate;
  DateTime? endDate;
  String? durasiEvent;
  String? jumlahTitik;
  String? statusArtis;
  String? artis1;
  String? artis2;
  String? artis3;
  String? artis4;
  String? recomendedPackage;
  String? valueMainPackage;
  String? suggestionNilaiSponsor;
  String? mainTitlingByGg;
  String? trialSellingProduct;
  String? brandingAndProduction;
  String? promotionAllContentOffline;
  String? promotionAllContentOnline;
  String? postEventAmplification;
  String? complimentaryTicketDanId;
  String? decisionTimelineBrandProfile;
  dynamic suggestionBrand1;
  dynamic suggestionBrand2;
  String? decisionStatus;
  dynamic sendToCeBrand1;
  dynamic feedbackCeBrand1;
  dynamic decision1;
  dynamic keteranganDecision1;
  dynamic sendToCeBrand2;
  dynamic feedbackCeBrand2;
  dynamic decision2;
  dynamic keteranganDecision2;
  dynamic rejectionLetter;
  dynamic nilaiSponsorshipFinal;
  String? statusItem;
  String? catatanKerja;
  DateTime? tanggalProposalLengkapDiterima;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  List<HistoryUpdate>? historyUpdate;

  Proposal({
    this.id,
    this.uuidItem,
    this.proposalId,
    this.ro,
    this.ao,
    this.kota,
    this.venue,
    this.title,
    this.deskripsi,
    this.jenisEvent,
    this.targetAudience,
    this.klasifikasiEvent,
    this.startDate,
    this.endDate,
    this.durasiEvent,
    this.jumlahTitik,
    this.statusArtis,
    this.artis1,
    this.artis2,
    this.artis3,
    this.artis4,
    this.recomendedPackage,
    this.valueMainPackage,
    this.suggestionNilaiSponsor,
    this.mainTitlingByGg,
    this.trialSellingProduct,
    this.brandingAndProduction,
    this.promotionAllContentOffline,
    this.promotionAllContentOnline,
    this.postEventAmplification,
    this.complimentaryTicketDanId,
    this.decisionTimelineBrandProfile,
    this.suggestionBrand1,
    this.suggestionBrand2,
    this.decisionStatus,
    this.sendToCeBrand1,
    this.feedbackCeBrand1,
    this.decision1,
    this.keteranganDecision1,
    this.sendToCeBrand2,
    this.feedbackCeBrand2,
    this.decision2,
    this.keteranganDecision2,
    this.rejectionLetter,
    this.nilaiSponsorshipFinal,
    this.statusItem,
    this.catatanKerja,
    this.tanggalProposalLengkapDiterima,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.historyUpdate,
  });

  factory Proposal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Proposal(
        id: json["id"],
        uuidItem: json["uuid_item"],
        proposalId: json["proposal_id"],
        ro: json["ro"],
        ao: json["ao"],
        kota: json["kota"],
        venue: json["venue"],
        title: json["title"],
        deskripsi: json["deskripsi"],
        jenisEvent: json["jenis_event"],
        targetAudience: json["target_audience"],
        klasifikasiEvent: json["klasifikasi_event"],
        startDate: json["start_date"] == null
            ? null
            : DateTime.parse(json["start_date"]),
        endDate:
            json["end_date"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["end_date"]),
        durasiEvent: json["durasi_event"],
        jumlahTitik: json["jumlah_titik"],
        statusArtis: json["status_artis"],
        artis1: json["artis_1"],
        artis2: json["artis_2"],
        artis3: json["artis_3"],
        artis4: json["artis_4"],
        recomendedPackage: json["recomended_package"],
        valueMainPackage: json["value_main_package"],
        suggestionNilaiSponsor: json["suggestion_nilai_sponsor"],
        mainTitlingByGg: json["main_titling_by_gg"],
        trialSellingProduct: json["trial_selling_product"],
        brandingAndProduction: json["branding_and_production"],
        promotionAllContentOffline: json["promotion_all_content_offline"],
        promotionAllContentOnline: json["promotion_all_content_online"],
        postEventAmplification: json["post_event_amplification"],
        complimentaryTicketDanId: json["complimentary_ticket_dan_id"],
        decisionTimelineBrandProfile: json["decision_timeline_brand_profile"],
        suggestionBrand1: json["suggestion_brand_1"],
        suggestionBrand2: json["suggestion_brand_2"],
        decisionStatus: json["decision_status"],
        sendToCeBrand1: json["send_to_ce_brand_1"],
        feedbackCeBrand1: json["feedback_ce_brand_1"],
        decision1: json["decision_1"],
        keteranganDecision1: json["keterangan_decision_1"],
        sendToCeBrand2: json["send_to_ce_brand_2"],
        feedbackCeBrand2: json["feedback_ce_brand_2"],
        decision2: json["decision_2"],
        keteranganDecision2: json["keterangan_decision_2"],
        rejectionLetter: json["rejection_letter"],
        nilaiSponsorshipFinal: json["nilai_sponsorship_final"],
        statusItem: json["status_item"],
        catatanKerja: json["catatan_kerja"],
        tanggalProposalLengkapDiterima:
            json["tanggal_proposal_lengkap_diterima"] == null
                ? null
                : DateTime.parse(json["tanggal_proposal_lengkap_diterima"]),
        createdAt: json["created_at"],
        updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
        historyUpdate: json["history_update"] == null
            ? []
            : List<HistoryUpdate>.from(
                json["history_update"]!.map((x) => HistoryUpdate.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "uuid_item": uuidItem,
        "proposal_id": proposalId,
        "ro": ro,
        "ao": ao,
        "kota": kota,
        "venue": venue,
        "title": title,
        "deskripsi": deskripsi,
        "jenis_event": jenisEvent,
        "target_audience": targetAudience,
        "klasifikasi_event": klasifikasiEvent,
        "start_date":
            "${startDate!.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${startDate!.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${startDate!.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "end_date":
            "${endDate!.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${endDate!.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${endDate!.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "durasi_event": durasiEvent,
        "jumlah_titik": jumlahTitik,
        "status_artis": statusArtis,
        "artis_1": artis1,
        "artis_2": artis2,
        "artis_3": artis3,
        "artis_4": artis4,
        "recomended_package": recomendedPackage,
        "value_main_package": valueMainPackage,
        "suggestion_nilai_sponsor": suggestionNilaiSponsor,
        "main_titling_by_gg": mainTitlingByGg,
        "trial_selling_product": trialSellingProduct,
        "branding_and_production": brandingAndProduction,
        "promotion_all_content_offline": promotionAllContentOffline,
        "promotion_all_content_online": promotionAllContentOnline,
        "post_event_amplification": postEventAmplification,
        "complimentary_ticket_dan_id": complimentaryTicketDanId,
        "decision_timeline_brand_profile": decisionTimelineBrandProfile,
        "suggestion_brand_1": suggestionBrand1,
        "suggestion_brand_2": suggestionBrand2,
        "decision_status": decisionStatus,
        "send_to_ce_brand_1": sendToCeBrand1,
        "feedback_ce_brand_1": feedbackCeBrand1,
        "decision_1": decision1,
        "keterangan_decision_1": keteranganDecision1,
        "send_to_ce_brand_2": sendToCeBrand2,
        "feedback_ce_brand_2": feedbackCeBrand2,
        "decision_2": decision2,
        "keterangan_decision_2": keteranganDecision2,
        "rejection_letter": rejectionLetter,
        "nilai_sponsorship_final": nilaiSponsorshipFinal,
        "status_item": statusItem,
        "catatan_kerja": catatanKerja,
        "tanggal_proposal_lengkap_diterima":
            "${tanggalProposalLengkapDiterima!.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${tanggalProposalLengkapDiterima!.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${tanggalProposalLengkapDiterima!.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "created_at": createdAt,
        "updated_at": updatedAt,
        "history_update": historyUpdate == null
            ? []
            : List<dynamic>.from(historyUpdate!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class HistoryUpdate {
  int? id;
  String? status;
  int? userId;
  int? proposalItemId;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  HistoryUpdate({
    this.id,
    this.status,
    this.userId,
    this.proposalItemId,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory HistoryUpdate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HistoryUpdate(
        id: json["id"],
        status: json["status"],
        userId: json["user_id"],
        proposalItemId: json["proposal_item_id"],
        createdAt: json["created_at"],
        updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "status": status,
        "user_id": userId,
        "proposal_item_id": proposalItemId,
        "created_at": createdAt,
        "updated_at": updatedAt,
      };
}

class Link {
  String? url;
  String? label;
  bool? active;

  Link({
    this.url,
    this.label,
    this.active,
  });

  factory Link.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Link(
        url: json["url"],
        label: json["label"],
        active: json["active"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "url": url,
        "label": label,
        "active": active,
      };
}
```

My view

```
class ProposalTab extends GetView<BaseController> {
  ProposalTab({super.key});

  late CustomTheme customTheme;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    customTheme = AppTheme.customTheme;

    showColor(String status) {
      if (status == "REJECTED" || status == "CANCELED") {
        return "REJECTED";
      } else if (status == "SUBMITED") {
        return "SUBMITED";
      } else if (status == "DONE") {
        return "DONE";
      } else if (status == "PROPOSAL REVIEW BY HOP") {
        return "PROPOSAL REVIEW BY HOP";
      } else if (status == "FORWARD TO OTHER FUNCTION") {
        return "FORWARD TO OTHER FUNCTION";
      } else if (status == "PROPOSAL REVIEW BY CE/BRAND") {
        return "PROPOSAL REVIEW BY CE/BRAND";
      } else {
        return "GRAY";
      }
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        MyContainer(
          margin: MySpacing.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 10),
          padding: MySpacing.xy(12, 4),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              MySpacing.width(16),
              Expanded(
                child: Obx(
                  () => TextFormField(
                    initialValue: controller.txtSearch.value,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      controller.txtSearch.value = value;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Search...',
                      hintStyle: MyTextStyle.bodyMedium(),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      focusedErrorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    style: MyTextStyle.bodyMedium(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        controller.obx(
          (state) => Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: MySpacing.zero,
              itemCount: state!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final proposal = state[index];
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Get.toNamed(
                      '/proposal-detail',
                      arguments: proposal.uuidItem,
                    );
                  },
                  child: singleTask(
                    subject: proposal.title,
                    statusText: proposal.statusItem,
                    submissionDate:
                        proposal.tanggalProposalLengkapDiterima.toString(),
                    status: showColor(proposal.statusItem.toString()),
                    task: proposal.deskripsi,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          onLoading: Shimmer.fromColors(
            baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
            highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 8,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return singleTask(
                  subject: "...........",
                  statusText: "...........",
                  submissionDate: "...........",
                  status: "...........",
                  task: "...........",
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          onError: (error) => Center(
            child: Text(
              error.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          onEmpty: const Center(
            child: Text(
              "Proposal data is empty",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget singleTask(
      {String? subject,
      String? task,
      String? submissionDate,
      String? statusText,
      String? status}) {
    IconData iconData;
    Color iconBG, iconColor, statusColor;
    switch (status) {
      case "REJECTED":
        iconBG = customTheme.colorError;
        iconColor = customTheme.onError;
        iconData = LucideIcons.file;
        statusColor = customTheme.colorError;
        break;
      case "SUBMITED":
        iconBG = theme.colorScheme.primary;
        iconColor = theme.colorScheme.onPrimary;
        iconData = LucideIcons.file;
        statusColor = theme.colorScheme.primary;
        break;
      case "DONE":
        iconBG = customTheme.colorSuccess;
        iconColor = customTheme.onSuccess;
        iconData = LucideIcons.file;
        statusColor = customTheme.colorSuccess;
        break;
      case "CANCELED":
        iconBG = customTheme.colorError;
        iconColor = customTheme.onError;
        iconData = LucideIcons.file;
        statusColor = customTheme.colorError;
        break;
      case "PROPOSAL REVIEW BY HOP":
        iconBG = customTheme.estatePrimary;
        iconColor = customTheme.onInfo;
        iconData = LucideIcons.file;
        statusColor = customTheme.estatePrimary;
      case "FORWARD TO OTHER FUNCTION":
        iconBG = customTheme.medicarePrimary;
        iconColor = customTheme.onInfo;
        iconData = LucideIcons.file;
        statusColor = customTheme.medicarePrimary;
      case "PROPOSAL REVIEW BY CE/BRAND":
        iconBG = customTheme.estatePrimary;
        iconColor = customTheme.onInfo;
        iconData = LucideIcons.file;
        statusColor = customTheme.estatePrimary;
        break;
      default:
        iconBG = customTheme.disabledColor;
        iconColor = customTheme.onDisabled;
        iconData = LucideIcons.file;
        statusColor = customTheme.disabledColor;
        break;
    }

    return MyContainer.bordered(
      paddingAll: 16,
      margin: MySpacing.fromLTRB(20, 8, 20, 8),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
      borderRadiusAll: 4,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: MySpacing.all(6),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: iconBG, shape: BoxShape.circle),
            child: Icon(
              iconData,
              color: iconColor,
              size: 20,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: MySpacing.left(16),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MyText.bodyLarge(
                    subject!,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                    fontWeight: 600,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: MySpacing.top(2),
                    child: MyText.bodySmall(
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      task!,
                      color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground.withAlpha(160),
                      fontWeight: 600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: MySpacing.left(16),
                child: MyText.bodySmall(
                  submissionDate!,
                  fontSize: 12,
                  letterSpacing: 0.2,
                  color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                  muted: true,
                  fontWeight: 600,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: MySpacing.top(2),
                child: MyText.bodyMedium(
                  statusText!,
                  color: statusColor,
                  letterSpacing: 0,
                  fontWeight: status == 3 ? 600 : 500,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Why my shimmer loading `onLoading` not showing while api request? But the listview show after api is called?

Need advice. Thanks